# CentOS - Files to Copy to get Consistent MIME-type detection in PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, apache-1.3, mime-type

I have the same website (written in PHP) running on two servers. I've tried uploading the same exact file to both servers through the website. On one of the servers, the file's mimetype is detected as `video/mpeg`, on the other it's detected as `application/octet-stream`. I want to get the servers to detect the mimetype the same way, and I'm assuming I can do this by copying some files from one server to the other. Which files do I need to copy?

The servers are also running different versions of CentOS: 5.9 and 5.10.  Apache version on the server that's showing `application/octet-stream` is 1.3.37.  On the other it's 2.2.3.

Edited: I also noticed the server that is detecting application/octet-stream (the undesired mimetype), has the line `LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so` commented out of its etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file while in the other's httpd.conf file it is not commented out, if case that has an effect.

Also tried adding the line to httpd.conf, but it did not work:

`AddType video/mpeg .mpg`

Comment: Perhaps someone hand edited mime.types in the apache config dir on one of the servers.  That is used by mime_module (as apposed to mime_magic_module).